# MySQL Select And Count Date Range: Doesn't work crossing the month barrier

Tags: php, mysql, select, count, date-range

Can you please tell me why this works:

```
$customer_data_date14daysAgo = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM tableName WHERE datetime BETWEEN '$date14daysAgo%' and 
'$dateToday%' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

But this doesn't?

```
$customer_data_date30daysAgo = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM tableName WHERE datetime BETWEEN '$date30daysAgo%' and 
'$dateToday%' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

PHP:

```
$dateToday = date ( 'Y-M-d', strtotime ( '-0 day' . $date ) );   
$date14daysAgo = date ( 'Y-M-d', strtotime ( '-14 day' . $date ) );   
$date30daysAgo = date ( 'Y-M-d', strtotime ( '-1 month' . $date ) );
```

$dateToday = 2010-Oct-28
$date14daysAgo = 2010-Oct-21
$date30daysAgo = 2010-Sep-28

The only difference is that the second query spans the Sep - Oct barrier.

If I set the date manually to 2010-Oct-01 until today - it works
But if its 2010-Sep-30 until today - it stops working

Thank you!

Comment: What stops working??? What's the problem?

Comment: please explain to us clearly what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: What stops working is that it stops counting correctly - as soon as it crosses the "month border" from Sep to Oct - somehow it doesn't count the actual number, but instead counts and report an inaccurate number.

Comment: ... or it counts 0. However, when I search within the same Month - the readings are perfectly accurate

Comment: why you not use CURRENT_DATE for $dateToday = date ( 'Y-M-d', strtotime ( '-0 day' . $date ) );?

Answer (score 1):

if you want search data one month ago until the current date, perhaps this can help:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

and if you want to show 1 month ago( the current date not included), you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table 
WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

but if i'm not misunderstand.

---

by following your question, try like:

```
$customer_data_date30daysAgo = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM tableName WHERE datetime BETWEEN '".$date30daysAgo."%' and 
'".$dateToday."%' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hi, this didn't work for me because I didn't yet figure out how to add the wildcard "%" variable in in equation.
  
My dates are set as DateTime like this: "2010-Nov-02 : 10:25:34" - So I tried: 
  
 $customer_data_date30daysAgo = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table WHERE datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE()%,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()%") or die(mysql_error());   

But it shows mysql syntax error - how can I add the wildcard variable to ignore anything after yyyy-mm-dd?

Thank you!

Comment: if you want to use "%", try like this: '".$bla."%'

Comment: Can you clarify - I don't understand the syntax. How do I write it: CURRENT_DATE()%

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't like being given dates with month names (e.g. "2010-Oct-28"). The [recommended format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) is all numeric like this: 2010-10-28.

So when you call the [php date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), ask for it in that format:

```
$dateToday = date ( 'Y-m-d', strtotime ( '-0 day' . $date ) );   
$date14daysAgo = date ( 'Y-m-d', strtotime ( '-14 day' . $date ) );   
$date30daysAgo = date ( 'Y-m-d', strtotime ( '-1 month' . $date ) );
```

That will give these strings:
$dateToday = 2010-10-28
$date14daysAgo = 2010-10-21
$date30daysAgo = 2010-10-28

And that should make your SQL work better.

Answer (score 0):

just wrote an article how to work with dates. it includes code samples for MySQL as well:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates